# mat-toolbar-row stacking on top of each other

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-material2

I have this problem with `<mat-toolbar-row>`. I tried using flexbox and grid on the `<mat-toolbar>` with **main-content** class. But they keep stacking a little bit.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    // SOME CODE
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar class="main-toolbar" color="primary">
      <mat-icon><img src="../../assets/images/x1/outline_navigate_before_black_24dp.png" alt=""></mat-icon>
      <span>R</span>
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon><img src="../../assets/images/x1/round_menu_black_24dp.png" alt=""></mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <!-- /////////////////////////// -->
    <!--  Home grid -->
    <!-- /////////////////////////// -->
      <mat-toolbar class="main-content">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
          <mat-card>
            <img src="../../assets/images/x1/round_add_black_24dp.png" alt="" mat-card-avatar>
            <mat-card-title>Lorem Ipsum</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>Lorem Ipsum</mat-card-subtitle>
          </mat-card>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
        <mat-toolbar-row>
          <mat-card>
            <img src="../../assets/images/x1/round_add_black_24dp.png" alt="" mat-card-avatar>
            <mat-card-title>Lorem Ipsum</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>Lorem Ipsum</mat-card-subtitle>
          </mat-card>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
        <mat-toolbar-row>
          <mat-card>
            <img src="../../assets/images/x1/round_add_black_24dp.png" alt="" mat-card-avatar>
            <mat-card-title>Lorem Ipsum</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>Lorem Ipsum</mat-card-subtitle>
          </mat-card>
        </mat-toolbar-row>

      </mat-toolbar>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

This is the scss of those elements

```
.main-content {
padding-top: 64px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: auto;
grid-template-columns: 1fr;

mat-card {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you look carefully it overlaps some pixels, only the bottom `<mat-toolbar-row>` has the full height.
[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ5bV.jpg)
[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGI5D.jpg)

Regards.

Comment: I'd normally suggest that you create a working Stackblitz example, but I suspect the problem is that you are trying to use components in a way that shouldn't be done by overriding the default layouts of both toolbar and card. Cards don't belong inside a toolbar based on material design specs and because they simply don't fit. I recommend you create you own custom component for this purpose - that will probably be a lot easier than getting MatToolbar and MatCard to work in a way that was never intended.

Comment: Ahhh maybe that’s it. Didn’t thought about it, I’ll check specs of each one. Thank you for your answer.